# Either toggling or remove class A and add class B on click with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have a jQuery mobile page that has a jQuery chat feature. Essentially I type something into the chat and then a few seconds later the bot responds.

Behind the chat feature and filling up the whole page is a class that has a background image, and I wish to have it so when I type into the text field and hit SEND the  background image class toggles to another class which has a different background image. I also wish it to have like a 2-3 second delay.

I have tried

```
$(function () {
$("#chatSend").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".tasteTheRainbow").toggleClass("orNot");
});
});
```

Here is my JSfiddle...the background image does not show up but its there. https://jsfiddle.net/mattmega4/d9yodhtm/

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be this:

```
$(this).closest(".tasteTheRainbow").fadeTo('fast', 0, function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("orNot").fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

See the DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/d9yodhtm/3/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, it works great in the jsfiddle, but unfortunately it does not work in my mobile app. Does that mean that there is something wrong with my code?    Thank you

Comment: @MatthewSingleton yes most probably. You should pay attention to the css classes in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my question. I can get the image to change, but not the delay, but I can keep looking into that. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button#chatSend").click(function(){
    $(".tasteTheRainbow").addClass("orNot");
});
});
```

Comment: You use `setTimeout()` in your jsfiddle for the canned response. Can't you use it for the delay?

Comment: Thanks! And to everybody that helped me!

Comment: the setTimout() was the solution btw for the delay, i tried a few other methods but that was the right method